# Why am I getting the ImportError ../lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_uri_ref based on order of import?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, matplotlib

On one of my experiments, I found this strange behavior.
If I do

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

`import cv2`

Then I get ImportError

> ImportError: /home/deep/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0: undefined symbol: g_uri_ref
> [image]

But, If I change the order of imports as

`import cv2`

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Everything runs fine. Matplotlib version is 3.2.2 and cv2 version is 4.3.0
I tried to see if I could find some similar problem or explanation, but have not yet found an answer. I'm not sure why this problem occurs and how to fix it.

Comment: Hi I got this error after installing pyQT5. It could be a version problem between opencv-python and pyqt5. 
If I figured my problem out, I will tell you.

Answer (score 0):

set up a virtual enviroment (best with anaconda) to be save and try:

```
pip3 install opencv-python==4.5.1.48
```

and

```
pip3 install pyqt5
```

So far it works, but I get other errors. owever, this could be due to my own script. I will update if I have more info.

Good luck

Comment: In my problem, simply reversing the order of imports works. I think setting up virtual environments may not be required. It would help if you could figure out why the problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try install the mentioned package, libgobject-2.0.so.0 from here:   https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libgobject-2.0.so.0
For Ubuntu:
Step 1: Update the package index:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 2: Install libglib2.0-0 deb package:

```
sudo apt-get install libglib2.0-0
```